# ciclo de if o for en google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un scripts de google app que junto con una fórmula me oculta las columnas donde contenga el número de la columna y donde la columna contenga el número uno me la oculta automático.  Todo bien hasta este punto lo que deseo es tener una condición como un `if` o un ciclo `for` que me permita colocar mi regla a todas las columnas y no hacerlo yo manualmente. Un poco del código:

```js
function hideColumns(c,a) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(c, a);

};

function hideC(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('B2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('F1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('F2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)


var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('D1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('D2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('C2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('E1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('E2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('A2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('G1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('G2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('H1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('H2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('H1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('H2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('I1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('I2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('J1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('J2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('K1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('K2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('L1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('L2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('M1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('M2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('N1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('N2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('O1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('O2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('P1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('P2').getValue();

hideColumns(c,a)

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('Q1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('Q2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('R1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('R2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('S1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('S2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)



  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('T1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('T2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('U1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('U2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('V1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('V2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)
  

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('W1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('W2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('X1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('X2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('Y1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('Y2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)

  
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var c = spreadsheet.getRange('Z1').getValue();
  var a = spreadsheet.getRange('Z2').getValue();

  hideColumns(c,a)
}

function showColumns(c,a) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(c, a);

  

};
```

Como ven le estoy indicando que columnas tendrán esta regla manualmente como por ejemplo b, c, d, e lo que quiero es no declarar una a una y hacer que tome todas las columnas de la hoja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código tiene varios "problemas"

1. No está claro porque pones las columna a ocultar en la primera celda de la fila 1 y la cantidad de columnas a ocultar en la celda de la fila 2.
2. Uso de `var`. En los ejemplos viejos de Google Apps Script se incluye `var` porque era la única forma de declarar una variable en el ámbito local. Desde que incorporó el nuevo runtime lo recomendado es usar `const` y `let` y dejar el uso de `var` sólo para los casos en los que realmente se requiera.
3. Uso repetitivo de `getRange(referencia).getValue()`. Esto es un problema las llamadas a métodos de Google Apps Script son lentas. En este caso puedes leer todos los valores de las primera fila usando `spreadsheet.getRange('A1:Z2').getValues()` (este enunciado te devolverá una Array conteniendo un Array de números, cadenas de texto, booleanos o objetos Date dependiendo del valor de cada celda por cada una de las filas. Para las celdas  vacías te devolverá una cadena de texto vacía.

Asumiendo que el código en la pregunta hace lo que requieres, c continuación incluyo un ejemplo de como se podría usar `for` para evitar repetir código por cada columna así como del uso de `getRange(referencia).getValues()`:

```
function hideColumns(){
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const values = sheet.getRange('A1:Z2').getValues(); // lee todos los valores
  for(let i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++){ // itera por cada una de las columnas
     let c = values[0][i]; // toma el valor de la primera fila, columna i
     let a = values[1][i]; // toma el valor de la segunda fila, columna i
     sheet.hideColumns(c,a);
  }
}
```

Nota: Para tener un script más eficiente en términos de tiempo de ejecución usa el servicio avanzado de Google Sheets.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced

Comment: muchísimas gracias Rubén agradecido con la respuesta la adapte a mi código y ahora si oculta las columnas que cumplan la condición  y ya solo tengo que asignar de donde a donde. gracias por el apoyo y tiempo prestado.

Comment: @josegarcia No hay de que. Por favor lee [Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

No entendí del todo el problema, y estoy casi seguro que `hideColumns` no funciona pasándole celdas, pero bueno, adaptando tu implementación a algo de cómo se iteraría para no hacerlo manualmente sería algo así.

```js
function hideColumns(c,a) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideColumns(c, a);
};

function hideColumnsWith1(){
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var data = spreadsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    data.forEach(function (row) {
        // Supongamos que el 1 que te interesa está en la fila 1
        if (row[0] == 1) {
            hideColumns(row[0],row[1])
        }
    });
}

function showColumns(c,a) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().showColumns(c, a);  
};
```

Me cuentas si reproduce el resultado esperado y sino lo vamos editando, porque sinceramente no logro entender qué es exactamente lo que tienes que hacer.

Comment: ya te explico agregare una foto a mi pregunta para que veas mejor actualmente mi scripts oculta todas las columnas donde la fila que le tengo asignada la regla de como resultado cero. con una formula tengo que cuando esribas algun numero en la columna arriba se convierte en 1. y ya con eso no ocultara esa columna